# Seg fault when trying to access two dimensional vector element

Tags: c++, caching, vector, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to model a set-associative cache with C++11, but I'm going wrong somewhere with my initialization or my method of accessing, or perhaps I need to come up with a better data structure to use...

Here are my private variable declarations:

```
private:
    int numSets; // Use this to control indexing
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long> >cache;
```

Here's my constructor (played around with resize/reserve and initializing the values a bunch):

```
        SetAssociativeCache(int associativity) : numSets(512/associativity){

        // Initialize the cache
        for(int i = 0; i < numSets; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < (512/numSets); j++)
                cache[i][j] = 0;
        }
```

And here's where I'm accessing it inside a member function:

```
unsigned long long line = cache[setIndex][addrOffset]; // Is this right?
```

At the time of this first access, setIndex is set to 0, and addrOffset is set to 20. Upon execution of this line, the program seg faults and crashes.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm assuming its just a silly mistake I'm not seeing.

### New Code (Still seg faulting)

```
    SetAssociativeCache(int associativity) : numSets(512/associativity) {

        // Initialize the cache
        for(int i = 0; i < numSets; i++){
            std::vector<unsigned long long> temp;
            cache.push_back(temp);
            for(int j = 0; j < (512/numSets); j++)
                cache[i].push_back(0);
        }
```

### GDB Output:

```
151   unsigned long long line = cache[setIndex][addrOffset];
(gdb) s
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >, std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long> > > >::operator[] (this=0x28fec4, __n=0)
at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:771
771           { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb) s
std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >::operator[] (this=0x100, __n=20)
    at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:771
771           { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00404d38 in std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >::operator[] (this=0x100, __n=20)
     at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:771
771           { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00404d38 in std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long> >::operator[] (this=0x100, __n=20)
    at c:/mingw/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:771
771           { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
(gdb)
[Inferior 1 (process 6096) exited with code 030000000005]
```

Comment: well...you never initialize `cache`. At least not in those snippets

Comment: @RedAlert What I'm doing in the constructor isn't initializing it?  What should I be doing instead?

Comment: You should have started with something simpler, like `vector<int>`. Failing that, you should have simplified *back* to `vector<int>` before posting the problem.

Comment: you attempt to initialize the elements, but not `cache` itself. It starts out with no memory allocated to it, and you just start trying to index stuff that isn't allocated to `cache`.

Comment: How do I allocate the required memory to cache?

Comment: @Beta I've tried your advice with Red Alert's below answer and I'm still getting a seg fault... See my question edit for more details

Answer (score 1):

Since you segfault when reading from `std::vector` I am almost sure that you are trying to read address beyond of its bounds (that means `addrOffset` is too large). If you want to be sure, try using `cache.at(x).at(y)` instead of `operator[]` - `at()` member function checks the bounds and it will throw appropriate exception. I suggest you checking `size` of this vector first though and adjusting your algorithm to take it into account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numSets; i++){
    std::vector<unsigned long long> temp;
    cache.push_back(temp);
    for(int j = 0; j < (512/numSets); j++)
        cache[i].push_back(0);
}
```

Otherwise, you never allocate memory for `cache`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unfamiliar with how to work with two dimensional arrays.

Comment: You have to allocate memory to all arrays, not just 2D ones.

Comment: I've implemented this and it's still seg faulting on the access.

Comment: I've posted the GDB output from stepping through the instruction in my answer

Comment: @Riptyde4 You are accessing elements that are out of bounds, then. I don't have access to your full code so I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: That means numSets is >= 25. If numSets is 25, 512/25 = 20, and thus your inner vector goes from 0..19.

Comment: but that's not true... entering "info locals" into gdb before execution of the line reads shows that setIndex = 0 and addrOffset = 20. If the initialization worked then cache[0][20] should not cause a seg fault.

Comment: @Riptyde4 I just modified your initialization code to not seg fault. Since I don't know what you are using the 2D array for, it's up to you to make sure that the limits in those for loops are correct.